# How to produce bump with radial tangent input + noise texture on meridians of a sphere?

Tags: texturing, materials, bump

I'm trying to make like an exaggerated skid marks defect on extruded aluminum. I tried tangent input and noise texture, but the bump map is not working. I need it to be bumpy on the xz-plane if the extrusion is in the y-axis direction.

So my question is: why the bump map is not working?

I'm using blender 3.3 & Cycles renderer.

**Screenshot**
[image: Shader]

[image: Viewport]

With base color white.
[image: ViewportWhite]

Comment: Are you sure? Unplug the texture from the Base Color input to see it with just the bump on solid white.

Comment: @TheLabCat I did that, no bumps. I just added the color for clarification. I tried to remove tangent, the bump map works fine then. Also tried tangent in geometry node, does not work too.

Comment: Yeah, that's weird. The tangent vector seems to be causing the problem, but I don't know why - when it's used as a basis for (true) displacement, it works just fine - https://ibb.co/nsXLx59  - (The reason for the map range node in my setup is that though Noise textures are supposed to be in a 0-1 range, 98% of their values fall between 0.25 and 0.75).

Comment: @ChristopherBennett perhaps the pattern generated by the tangent + noise is not suitable (too regular) for whatever algorithm being used in the bump node.

Comment: Yeah, that is incorrect AFAIK. They should be there. Check newer Blender versions.